# Session Problem with multiple Tabs

Tags: php, session

I have a search on my page where you have a filter Menu, a option for sorting, and a Pagebrowser. The Customer wanted, that if he searches something and clicks on a product and then clicks "back" or on "search" again, that the same search and results are shown again.

I dont want to pass all the Search Params with each link (bad urls), so I store all this data in the session. This works fine but there is one Problem:

A users opens the search and filters by "size=big" then opens a new tab and changes the filter to "size=small". There is now "size=small" in his session. So if he switches back on his first tab and clicks "page 2" there, then he sees the second page, but not for "size=big" as he expected, but for "size=small".

Is there a nice way to fix this without passing all the variables (many!) around all the time?

Comment: How do you define "bad urls"? Usually is more comfortable to put such parameters into the url, because this allows to bookmark, or email the links.

Comment: +1 to KingCrunch. You are going to cause yourself more problems if you do it in the way you suggest.

Comment: the link is very nice right now, like : www.x.y/category/product/, with all the stuff its more like /category/product/search1/value1/search2/value2/page/sorting where there might be up to 11 different search params. And this has to be everywhere even in the main menu links and those links have to change on ajax events .. this is not really a good solution i think

Comment: I agree with KingCrunch, "www.x.y/category/product/" is much worse than putting search params into link, as there's no way to "store" search results for later use. Also keeping all params while navigating around the page does not seem to be a good idea. I'm working on one system now, where I stored search params in session - it made more confusions than conveniences, so I had to switch to passing params via URL. As for changing URL on ajax events, Google solves this by putting variable stuff in URL after `#` character.

Comment: If you have a specific user base where you can control the browser their using, you can also use the HTML5 history API. Github does it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would strongly suggest putting the search in your link. It might make your links less »beautiful«, but I **hate** it when I can't send a search result to a friend by simply sending the link.

But to answer your question: Put a `search_id` in every form, that gets appended to the url. Then save the search in the session for that specific `search_id`. When the user refreshes the page, you can check if POST search variables are transmitted, or if there is one stored in the session for that specific `search_id`.

Comment: if you change your search the results are reloaded with ajax, so you never see the search url anyways as a user. (But it would be possible to show it to him somewhere)
I thought of somethink like this also, but how would i know when to create a new searchid. I dont know if the user changes his search or has opened a new tab and so wishes to create a new search? I could of course add a Button for a new search, but people might ignore it and change values anyway to change their search (especially if many vars are set and they only want to change one)

Comment: @Flo, about "*how would I know when to create new searchid*" - you might create new search ID on **every** search. E.g., you have search #1, you open it in another tab - now you have two #1 searches. You perform search in first tab - search #1 is replaced with #2, but you still have #1 in second tab. When another search is performed in second tab, search ID changes there from #1 to #3 (as #2 already is in first tab). This way, when performing new search, you can get search params from "previous" search, as you have ID of search that was performed in that exact tab.

Answer (score 0):

No.  right now, browsers implement cookies across all tabs, so you cannot have different cookies or sessions on different tabs.  Thus, the only way to store state is on the url.